# JS: How to open popup window and listen "reload" event?

Tags: javascript, popup

I need to open a popup window and execute some js code whenever content in that popup is loaded (DOMContentLoaded). For the first time I can listen for the load event `$(popup).on('load', ...)` but it won't work if I hit F5 (CMD+R) in that popup window. However, hitting reload hotkey will trigger `unload` event bound same way, but this isn't what  I need, I need - `load` event to be triggered.

Any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to reload the popup window while it's open or you want to reload the main page by whatever is in the popup window?

Comment: Reload the popup itself while it's open.